# Does fgets hold somehow where it stopped reading the FILE *stream?

Tags: programming, c

I am trying to get a sample program on how to write to a file:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char buff[1024];
  size_t len, idx;
  ssize_t wcnt;
  for (;;){
    if (fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin) == NULL)
      return 0;
    idx = 0;
    len = strlen(buff);
    do {
      wcnt = write(1,buff + idx, len - idx);
      if (wcnt == -1){ /* error */
        perror("write");
        return 1;
      }
      idx += wcnt;
    } while (idx < len);
  }
}
```

So my problem is this: Let's say I want to write a file of 20000 bytes so every time I can only write (at most) 1024 (buffer size).
Let's say that in my first attempt everything is going perfect and fgets() reads 1024 bytes and in my first do while I write 1024 bytes.
Then, since we wrote "len" bytes we exit the do-while loop.
**So now what??** The buffer is full from our previous reading.   **It seems to me that for some reason it is implied that fgets() will now continue reading from the point it reached in in-file the last time.** (buf[1024] here).
**How come, fgets() knows where it stopped reading in the in-file?**
I checked the man page :

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored in the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.
> fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when the end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*

So from that, I get that it returns a pointer to the first element of buf, which is always buf[0],
that's why I am confused.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question on stackoverflow instead of askubuntu, since this is a programming question?

Comment: it's for a shell script though.. but I guess I could try

Comment: Stackoverflow is for any programming language; you're question will reach a better audience...